# SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient - A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately on send

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ftp

I'm currently trying to connect to an FTP-server with a TcpClient.
For using FTPS as protocol I handle over the NetworkStream to a separate method that creates a *SslStream* with that one and then *SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient* is called and throws the exception **A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately on send**. The actual stream is initialized by the *TcpClient.GetStream*-method.
Actually the source code is from the Biko Library and you can find the part here: https://biko.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Biko/Starksoft%20Biko/Net/Ftp/FtpBase.cs

```
private Stream CreateSslStream(Stream stream)
    {
        // create an SSL or TLS stream that will close the client's stream
        SslStream ssl = new SslStream(stream, true, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(secureStream_ValidateServerCertificate), null);

        // choose the protocol
        SslProtocols protocol = SslProtocols.None;
        switch (_securityProtocol)
        {
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Tls1OrSsl3Explicit:
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Tls1OrSsl3Implicit:
                protocol = SslProtocols.Default;
                break;
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Ssl2Explicit:
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Ssl2Implicit:
                protocol = SslProtocols.Ssl2;
                break;
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Ssl3Explicit:
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Ssl3Implicit:
                protocol = SslProtocols.Ssl3;
                break;
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Tls1Explicit:
            case FtpSecurityProtocol.Tls1Implicit:
                protocol = SslProtocols.Tls;
                break;
            default:
                throw new FtpSecureConnectionException(String.Format("unexpected FtpSecurityProtocol type '{0}'", _securityProtocol.ToString()));
        }

        // note: the server name must match the name on the server certificate.
        try
        {
            // authenticate the client
            ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(_host, _clientCertificates, protocol, true);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException authEx)
        {
            throw new FtpAuthenticationException("Secure FTP session certificate authentication failed.", authEx);
        }

        return ssl;
    }
```

So, my question is, how could I modify the source code so that this exception isn't thrown anymore? I can't remove the authentication but the error should disappear, too. What causes this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.
I just updated to the newer version of the library. The problem was caused by threading problems which were solved by the author by adding *lock*-keywords.